# Simplifying Entropy $H(X-Y,X+Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent discrete random variables. Is it possible to simplify the joint entropy $H(X-Y,X+Y)$?

From my understanding, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $H(X+Y) = H(X,Y)$. However, I'm unsure how to proceed since $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ aren't independent. Ideally I want to get $H(X-Y,X+Y)$ in terms of $H(X)$ and $H(Y)$.

Comment: The equality you state for $H(X+Y)$ with $X$, $Y$ independent does not hold in general. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it only holds $H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y)$.

Comment: For example if $X$ may be 0 or 1 uniformly and $Y$ may be 0 or 1 uniformly then $H(X+Y)=2\frac14\log4+\frac12\log2=\frac32 \text{bits}$ but $H(X)$ is 1 bit and $H(Y)$ is 1 bit so $H(X)+H(Y)=2$ bits. We lose 1/2 bit of information because of adding $x$ and $y$, so that the two cases $x=0,y=1$ and $x=1, y=0$ are mixed into one event.

Answer (score 3):

As Stelios comments, $H(X+Y) = H(X,Y)$ is false. You probably meant $H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y)$, which is quite a different thing.

Now, calling $U=X+Y$, $V=X-Y$, we have $X=\frac12 (U+V)$ and $Y=\frac12(U-V)$

Hence the pairs $(X,Y)$ and $(U,V)$ are related by a one-to-one function. Hence they carry the same information, and their (joint) entropies are the same.

That is

$$H(X+Y,X-Y)=H(U,V)=H(X,Y) = H(X)+H(Y)$$

The last equality holds only when $X,Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

$$H(X+Y,X-Y)=H(X)+H(Y)$$

---

Proof:
$$
H(X+Y,X-Y)=\\
-\sum_{x+y}\sum_{x-y}p(x+y,x-y)\log(p(x+y,x-y))
$$
However, since $2x=(x+y)+(x-y)$ and $2y=(x+y)-(x-y)$, all of the distinct terms in the sums are reproduced if we sum $\sum_x\sum_y$, and similarly the probabilities $p(x+y,x-y)=p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$, so
$$
H(X+Y,X-Y)=-\sum_x\sum_y p(x)p(y)\log p(x)p(y)\\
=H(X)+H(Y).
$$

It might be interesting to do the calculation for a simple case such as $X=0,1$ and $Y=0,1$ with equal probabilities and check that the sums come out correctly.

Incidentally if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, by almost the same argument as above,
$$
H(X+Y,X-Y)=H(X,Y).
$$
The only thing which needs to change is that we must write the probabilities as $p(x,y)$ not $p(x)p(y)$. That results in the usual formula for $H(X,Y)$.